# Javascript: change onchange AND use this-parameter

Tags: javascript, onchange

By searching the net I've found out that I cannot use `document.getElementById("myid").onchange="myfunc(this);";` since I have to assign a function instead of a string. But when I use `document.getElementById("myid").onchange = myfunc(this);` instead, what will `this` refer to? I want `this` to be the HTML element which is triggering the onchange event, not the function where I'm changing the onchange attribute.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myid").onchange = myfunc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is not to pass the element as first argument to the function, but to reference the element within the function with `this`, as `this` will be bound to that element automatically. This is from the [MDN article on `onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), but it is true for all `on`-event properties:

> Within the handler, `this` will be the element upon which the event was triggered.

So you can just write:

```
document.getElementById("myid").onchange = myfunc;
```

... and in your function:

```
function myfunc() {
    console.log(this.id + ' changed'); // you can just refer to `this`
}
```

If for some reason you really need the first argument of the function to be the relevant element, then you can use `bind`:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myid");
elem.onchange = myfunc.bind(elem, elem);
```

Note that `elem` is specified twice; the first time for defining `this`, and the second time for the value of the first argument.

So now this will work:

```
function myfunc(elem) {
    console.log(elem.id + ' changed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the event and take the source element from it:

```
function myfunc(ev) {
    console.log(ev.srcElement);
}

document.getElementById("myid").onchange = myfunc;
```

In your example, you are not referencing the function with the eventhandler, but executing the function. That's why `this` is probably referencing the Window (depending on where this line code is) or other element.

But `this` can help when you define the eventhandler as an attribute of an html element:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change